# Bootstrap's modal doesn't load well values from Struts2

Tags: javascript, jsp, twitter-bootstrap-3, struts2, bootstrap-modal

I am trying to a web with struts 2, hibernate and MySQL. 
[image: ArrayList from propietarios with iterator for load his values]

I show this values with

```
                    <s:iterator value="propietarios">

                        <fieldset>
                            <legend>
                                ID:
                                <s:property value="idpropietario" />
                            </legend>
                            Nombre:
                            <s:property value="nombre" />
                            <br> Apellidos:
                            <s:property value="apellidos" />
                            <br> Teléfono:
                            <s:property value="telefono" />
                            <p>
                                <s:a action="VerPropiedades">Ver Propiedades
                <s:param name="idpropietario">
                                        <s:property value="idpropietario" />
                                    </s:param>
                                </s:a>
                            <div id="BorrarPropietario<s:property value="idpropietario" />"
                                class="modal fade in">
                                <div class="modal-dialog">
                                    <div class="modal-content">

                                        <div class="modal-header">
                                            <h4 class="modal-title">
                                                Dar de baja a:
                                                <s:property value="nombre" />
                                                <s:property value="%{apellidos}" />
                                            </h4>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="modal-body">
                                            <h4>¡Atención!</h4>
                                            <p>Si borra a dicho propietario todas las propiedades
                                                bajo su nombre se borrarán. ¿Está seguro de la operación?
                                            </p>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="modal-footer">
                                            <div class="btn-group">
                                                <s:a action="BorrarPropietario" theme="bootstrap"
                                                    class="btn btn-danger">
                                                    <s:param name="idpropietario">
                                                        <s:property value="%{idpropietario}" />
                                                    </s:param>

                                            Aceptar</s:a>


                                                <button class="btn btn-info" data-dismiss="modal">
                                                    Cancelar</button>



                                            </div>
                                        </div>

                                    </div>
                                    <!-- /.modal-content -->
                                </div>
                                <!-- /.modal-dalog -->

                                <!-- esto hace que el modal se abra -->
                            </div>
                            <!-- /.modal -->
                            <a data-toggle="modal"
                                href="#BorrarPropietario<s:property value="idpropietario" />"
                                class="btn btn-danger btn-xs"><span
                                class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span>Eliminar</a>
                            <!-- Modal -->
                            <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
                                <div class="modal-dialog">
                                    <!-- Modal content-->
                                    <div class="modal-content">
                                        <div class="modal-header">
                                            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                                            <h4 class="modal-title">Editar propietario</h4>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="modal-body">
                                            <center>
                                                <p>
                                                    <s:form action="EditarPropietario" method="post"
                                                        role="form">

  ID => <s:textfield name="idpropietario" value="%{idpropietario}"
                                                            readonly="true" />
                                                        <p>
                                                            <s:label class="control-label" value="Nombre  "></s:label>
                                                            <s:textfield name="nombre" value="%{nombre}"
                                                                required="" />
                                                        <p>
                                                            <s:label class="control-label" value="Apellidos"></s:label>
                                                            <s:textfield name="apellidos" value="%{apellidos}"
                                                                required="" />
                                                        <p>
                                                            <s:label class="control-label" value="Teléfono "></s:label>
                                                            <s:textfield name="telefono" value="%{telefono}"
                                                                required="" minlenght="10" maxlenght="10"
                                                                onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)" />

                                                            <s:submit class="btn btn-primary" value="Enviar" />
                                                    </s:form>
                                                </p>
                                            </center>
                                        </div>

                                    </div>

                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal"
                                href="#EditarPropietario<s:property value="idpropietario" />"
                                class="btn btn-warning btn-xs"><span
                                class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span>Editar</a>
                        </fieldset>
                        <p>
                    </s:iterator>
```

Delete works with a modal but the edit load values in the textfield but always with the first object. How I can for that this modal show the values from the object selected?
[image: Wrong values when show modal]

Only I need that his values load well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use different id for the modal that. Currently you are using the same id `myModal` that opens the first modal from the document.

See [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fg4anykb/) how to use different ids for dialogs that hold its own data.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
  <h2>Modal Example</h2>
  <!-- Trigger the modal with a button -->
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal1">Open Modal</button>

  <!-- Modal -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="myModal1" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
    
      <!-- Modal content-->
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
          <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <p>Some text in the modal 1.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
      </div>
      
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <h2>Modal Example</h2>
  <!-- Trigger the modal with a button -->
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal2">Open Modal</button>

  <!-- Modal -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="myModal2" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
    
      <!-- Modal content-->
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
          <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <p>Some text in the modal 2.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
      </div>
      
    </div>
  </div>
  
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

You are printing id with

```
<s:property value="idpropietario" />
```

That could be used to modify the id of the modal dialog used for editing.